# ASP.NET MVC : Null property values in model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Considering the following view excerpt :

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Something", Model.Property.SubProperty.Value) %>
```

I can handle the case when Property and SubProperty are null with :

```
<% if( Model.Property != null || Model.Property.SubProperty != null ) { %>
<%= Html.TextBox("Something", Model.Property.SubProperty.Value) %>
<% } %>
```

But I don't find this very clean. Anyone got an idea ?

I'm thinking about automapper. Good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you shoudl consider having your controller provide an object to the view that is more suitable to its needs.

Comment: Yes flattening might help or alternatively ensuring the Property would not be null.  Sometimes its better for the View to simply get a class created by the controller rather than hand the view an object from the Model.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that with AutoMapper